# How user can select city name while web scraping in python for justdial

Tags: python, selenium

I am very beginner in web **scraping**. I am trying to extract information from the just dial. I want that user can enter any city name of his own choice in program itself.  I am using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@id,'city')]").send_keys("Nashik")
```

This gives me an error

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: When I type in Nashik by hand at https://www.justdial.com/Kutch/Nashik-Dhol-Players/nct-11292548 it gives e 7 choices that drop down. Which should the script choose?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong locator :

try this instead :

```
driver.find_element(By.ID,"srchbx").send_keys("Nashik")
```

**PS :** - I would suggest you to launch broswer in full screen mode.

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

the above line you can write when you are creating object of any specific browser

Comment: *You are using the wrong locator* you base it on what? the OP didn't share the html or a link to the website.

Comment: @Guy : As mentioned by OP, he is extracting  just dial. so I used this `https://www.justdial.com/`

Comment: @Rohini_Vaidya : No, you have not. you are using xpath. check what you have posted.